# Using AJAX to send post request in nodeJS Express MongoDB

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, mongodb, express

I have got a newsletter section on my website with two fields, name and email. What I am after is that the user can fill the form and send it, saving the data in MongoDB and not reloading or redirecting the page, I am not interested in the result, all I want is to keep that data so in future, I can start sending newsletters, although refreshing just the newsletter section would be nice.

Bonus: The form is in the partial footer, so the form can be sent from any route in the website.

These are my efforts:

schema:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,  
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String, 
        unique: true, 
        required: true, 
        lowercase: true
    }
});
```

Server side:

```
//newsletter post
router.post("/", function(req, res){
    Newsletter.create(req.body.newsletter, function(err, newsletter) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            req.flash("success", "You have been successfully added to our newsletter! ");
            console.log(newsletter);
        }
    });
});
```

Footer partial:

```
<form id="newsletterForm" action="/" method="POST">
  <input id="newsletterName" type="text" name="newsletter[name]">
  <input id="newsletterEmail" type="email" name="newsletter[email]">
  <button id="submit" type="submit">Suscríbete</button>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
// Using Ajax to send a form without refreshing page
    $('#submit').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $.ajax({
            url: '/',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(html) {
            alert('data sent!');
            }
        });
        //return false; 
    });
```

At the moment is saving the data in MongoDB but after submiting the form the reload button of the browser is forever moving, no flash it's being shown and the form stays filled, however, it is console.logging the result.

Any help or pointing in a right direction would be great! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

send a response 200 from expressjs server

```
router.post("/", function(req, res){
    Newsletter.create(req.body.newsletter, function(err, newsletter) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err)
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({ message: 'success' });
            console.log(newsletter);
        }
    });
});


$('#submit').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({
        url: '/',
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function() {
          alert('data sent!');
          return false
        }
    });
    //return false; 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in this case, it still saves the data in MongoDB but the page reloads and crash: 
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: @GabrielNessi try now.i have modified above code.it should work

Comment: now it is reloading the page to a white page with {"message":"success"} printed, I want it to stay in the same page but sends a flash or something for the user to know that it worked.

Comment: @GabrielNessi try now. if possible can you create a sandbox

Comment: still the same problem, when the user submits it reloads and shows the json message in a blank page. I will have a look into sandbox, I have never created one.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing 2 things:-
1) you are not sending any response from the route, so it will not end it will keep waiting and scrolling,

```
router.post("/", function(req, res){
Newsletter.create(req.body.newsletter, function(err, newsletter) {
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
        res.status(200).json({ error: 'failed' });
    } else {
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'success' });
        console.log(newsletter);
    }
});
});
```

2) In ajax call, you should return false at end, so it will prevent page from reloading as it will not post form in page, so do

```
$('#submit').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({
        url: '/',
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(html) {
          alert('data sent!');
          //return false
        }
    });
    return false; 
});
```

Now, it will not reload the page.

Comment: Thanks for your help, after I submit the form it is reloading the page on the same route but the page is all white with {"message":"success"} printed. I want it to stay on the same page and just show to the user that the form was sent.

Comment: have you added return false in ajax call ?

Comment: Yeah, it does still reload the page :/

Comment: try to put return false, outside the ajax like the solution i updated

Comment: also you are passing id of button, you should pass id of form.,
$('#newsletterForm').submit();

Comment: I tried with return false inside and outside Ajax with the Id of form but now it does nothing, it doesn't reload or save anything on the database.